# Filter FormView by Query String

Tags: c#, .net, formview, linqdatasource

I have a FormView wired up to a LinqDataSource that I'd like to filter by query string. Basically, if an ID is passed in through the query string, I'd like to only show that record, otherwise if no ID is supplied just show them all. I have managed to get this to work using a couple different methods, however every time I try to save the data in the FormView I'm getting the exception: `Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Int32?' and 'Object'`.

The above exception is raised when I call `FormView.UpdateItem(true)`. Here is how I filter the LinqDataSource:

```
protected void ldsIncidents_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        e.Result = db.Incidents.Where(i => i.Incident_Number == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]));
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown when I call `FormView.UpdateItem(true)`. As soon as I remove the code from the `Selecting` event above, everything works as it should but I can no longer filter the data. I have also tried dynamically adding WhereParameters to the LinqDataSource, but the same thing happens. Does anybody know why this is happening or how to fix it? Here is my stack trace if it helps:

```
Exception Type: System.Web.Query.Dynamic.ParseException
Message: Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Int32?' and 'Object'
Stack Trace:
   at System.Web.Query.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.CheckAndPromoteOperands(Type signatures, String opName, Expression& left, Expression& right, Int32 errorPos)
   at System.Web.Query.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseComparison()
   at System.Web.Query.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd()
   at System.Web.Query.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr()
   at System.Web.Query.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseExpression()
   at System.Web.Query.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type resultType)
   at System.Web.Query.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
   at System.Web.Query.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(Type itType, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
   at System.Web.Query.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(IQueryable source, String predicate, Object[] values)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DynamicQueryableWrapper.Where(IQueryable source, String predicate, Object[] values)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceView.ExecuteQueryExpressions(IQueryable source, QueryContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceView.ExecuteQuery(IQueryable source, QueryContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.get_Controls()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlHelper.ExtractValuesFromBindableControls(IOrderedDictionary dictionary, Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlHelper.ExtractValuesFromBindableControls(IOrderedDictionary dictionary, Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlHelper.ExtractValuesFromBindableControls(IOrderedDictionary dictionary, Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlHelper.ExtractValuesFromBindableControls(IOrderedDictionary dictionary, Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlHelper.ExtractValuesFromBindableControls(IOrderedDictionary dictionary, Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlHelper.ExtractValuesFromBindableControls(IOrderedDictionary dictionary, Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlHelper.ExtractValuesFromBindableControls(IOrderedDictionary dictionary, Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControlHelper.ExtractValuesFromBindableControls(IOrderedDictionary dictionary, Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.ExtractRowValues(IOrderedDictionary fieldValues, Boolean includeKeys)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.HandleUpdate(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.UpdateItem(Boolean causesValidation)
   at PRIDE.Pages.Incidents.View.btnSaveIncident_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\hopfnejo\Documents\Development Projects\PRIDE\PRIDE\Pages\Incidents\View.aspx.cs:line 317
```

---

***EDIT***

Here are the contents of the FormView's `ItemUpdating` event:

```
protected void fvIncident_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TabContainer tc = fvIncident.FindControl("tcMain") as TabContainer;

    e.NewValues["Division"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("cboDivision") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["Safety"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("chkSafety") as CheckBox).Checked;
    e.NewValues["Quality"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("chkQuality") as CheckBox).Checked;
    e.NewValues["Cost"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("chkCost") as CheckBox).Checked;
    e.NewValues["Production"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("chkProduction") as CheckBox).Checked;
    e.NewValues["Environment"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("chkEnvironment") as CheckBox).Checked;
    e.NewValues["Department"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("cboDepartment") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["Area"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("cboArea") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["Initiated_By"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("txtInitiatedBy") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["KRA_Notes"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("txtKRANotes") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["Incident_type"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("cboIncidentType") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["Aspect_Affected"] = (tc.Tabs[0].FindControl("cboAspectAffected") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;

    e.NewValues["Incident_Level"] = (tc.Tabs[1].FindControl("cboIncidentLevel") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["ADM_Testing_Within_Guidelines"] = (tc.Tabs[1].FindControl("chkADMTestingWithinGuidelines") as CheckBox).Checked;
    e.NewValues["ADM_Testing_Required"] = (tc.Tabs[1].FindControl("chkADMTestingRequired") as CheckBox).Checked;
    e.NewValues["Number_Of_People_Involved"] = (tc.Tabs[1].FindControl("txtNumPeopleInvolved") as TextBox).Text;

    e.NewValues["Mill_State"] = (tc.Tabs[2].FindControl("cboMillState") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["Area_Downtime"] = (tc.Tabs[2].FindControl("txtDowntime") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["Production_Amount_Lost"] = (tc.Tabs[2].FindControl("txtProductionAmountLost") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["Production_Actual_or_Estimate"] = (tc.Tabs[2].FindControl("cboProductionActualOrEstimate") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["Production_Units"] = (tc.Tabs[2].FindControl("cboProductionUnits") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;

    e.NewValues["Environmental_Impact"] = (tc.Tabs[3].FindControl("txtEnvironmentalImpact") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["Environmental_Specialist_Notified"] = (tc.Tabs[3].FindControl("cboEnvironmentalSpecialistNotified") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["Environmental_Incident_Reportable_to_Government"] = (tc.Tabs[3].FindControl("cboEnvironmentalIncidentReportableToGovernment") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["Environmental_Governement_Agency_Involved"] = (tc.Tabs[3].FindControl("txtGovernmentAgencyInvolved") as TextBox).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((tc.Tabs[3].FindControl("txtDateReported") as TextBox).Text))
        e.NewValues["Environmental_Date_Reported"] = null;
    else
        e.NewValues["Environmental_Date_Reported"] = (tc.Tabs[3].FindControl("txtDateReported") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["Environmental_Action_Taken"] = (tc.Tabs[3].FindControl("txtEnforcementActionTaken") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["Environmental_Reference_Number"] = (tc.Tabs[3].FindControl("txtReferenceNumber") as TextBox).Text;

    e.NewValues["Procedures"] = (tc.Tabs[4].FindControl("txtProceduresAffected") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["Referances"] = (tc.Tabs[4].FindControl("txtReferences") as TextBox).Text;

    e.NewValues["Reviewed_By__BUL_"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtReviewedByBUL") as TextBox).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtSignOffDateBUL") as TextBox).Text))
        e.NewValues["Sign_Off_Date__BUL_"] = null;
    else
        e.NewValues["Sign_Off_Date__BUL_"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtSignOffDateBUL") as TextBox).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtPlannedReviewDate") as TextBox).Text))
        e.NewValues["Planned_Review_Date"] = null;
    else
        e.NewValues["Planned_Review_Date"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtPlannedReviewDate") as TextBox).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtPlannedCompletionDate") as TextBox).Text))
        e.NewValues["Planned_Completion_Date"] = null;
    else
        e.NewValues["Planned_Completion_Date"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtPlannedCompletionDate") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["Signed_Off_By__BGL_"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtSignedOffByBGL") as TextBox).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtSignOffDateBGL") as TextBox).Text))
        e.NewValues["Sign_Off_Date__BGL_"] = null;
    else
        e.NewValues["Sign_Off_Date__BGL_"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtSignOffDateBGL") as TextBox).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtActualReviewDate") as TextBox).Text))
        e.NewValues["Actual_Review_Date"] = null;
    else
        e.NewValues["Actual_Review_Date"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtActualReviewDate") as TextBox).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtActualCompletionDate") as TextBox).Text))
        e.NewValues["Actual_Completion_Date"] = null;
    else
        e.NewValues["Actual_Completion_Date"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtActualCompletionDate") as TextBox).Text;
    e.NewValues["Signed_Off_By__Mill_Manager_"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtSignedOffByMillManager") as TextBox).Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtSignOffDateMillManager") as TextBox).Text))
        e.NewValues["Sign_Off_Date__Mill_Manager_"] = null;
    else
        e.NewValues["Sign_Off_Date__Mill_Manager_"] = (tc.Tabs[8].FindControl("txtSignOffDateMillManager") as TextBox).Text;
}
```

***EDIT 2***

I have tried setting breakpoints in the only events I have handlers for related to the LinqDataSource and FormView, and none of the events are fired before the exception occurs. The events are:

- `LinqDataSource_Selecting`
- `FormView_ItemUpdating`
- `FormView_DataBound`

None of my breakpoints are reached after clicking the Save button. It blows up here, not very useful:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my FormView declaration:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvIncident" runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit" 
    DataSourceID="ldsIncidents" DataKeyNames="Incident_Number" 
    AllowPaging="True" CssClass="full" ondatabound="fvIncident_DataBound" 
    onitemupdating="fvIncident_ItemUpdating">
```

And my LinqDataSource declaration:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsIncidents" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="PRIDE.PRIDEDataContext" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" 
    TableName="Incidents" OrderBy="Incident_Number DESC" 
    onselecting="ldsIncidents_Selecting">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Comment: Try with : `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        e.Result = db.Incidents.Where(i => i.Incident_Number == id );
    }`

Comment: That is code is the same thing I already have in the `Selecting` event except with one more unnecessary step...

Comment: Please post the FormView and ItemTemplate declaration and setup code as well as how/where you call FormView.UpdateItem(true). Your error is elsewhere, it's not in the code you posted. Meaning, it is not CAUSED by the code you have posted, even though it might be thrown at this point.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin The formview code is 900 lines long (yup, it's a doozie). If I comment out the Selecting event everything appears to work as it should. The weird thing is the `Selecting` event doesn't even get fired when the exception is thrown. Since I don't expect anybody to go through 900 lines of FormView code, I guess a more appropriate question is how can I trace this problem down? I call `FormView.UpdateItem(true)` in a button, no other code other than try/catch.

Comment: The event does get fired on page load, but not when I'm saving from the button using `UpdateItem`.

Comment: What is happening on UpdateItem event handler and subsequently - is it trying to DataBind a GridView? Is the LinqDataSource being reused between the GridView and the FormView? I see that in the StackTrace. If so, then the Selecting event is being misused by the GridView when databinding using the same LinqDataSource. This is an educated guess based on your StackTrace : `at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind()`

Comment: @DavidKhaykin I've posted the code for the `ItemUpdating` event. Also, there is no GridView, just a FormView.

Comment: Not much help there. I assume Incident_Number is your DataKey? Does the update fail or work before the exception is thrown?

Comment: Correct, Incident_Number is the DataKey and the update fails before the exception is thrown.

Comment: I added more information, see my latest edit...

Comment: Can you enable JIT debugging and see if you can step through the FormView code and look at the state of objects where the error occurs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Alternately, you can wrap the UpdateItem() call in a try/catch and catch the ParseException, look at InnerException for any details; just for debugging of course, you can remove after you've solved the problem.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin, JIT is already enabled for all code types. I had the `UpdateItem` call in a try/catch block but removed it to demonstrate where the exception is being thrown. The inner exception is `null` :\

Comment: @Hoff maybe you should set a breakpoint on each point where a `Int32?` get a new value if it doesn't stop before you exception is thrown maybe a sub-object doesn't work like you expect it

Comment: Yeah I think that may be my next step. It just floors me because as soon as I remove the code from the `Selecting` event everything works exactly as it should. But yet the `Selecting` event doesn't even get fired when I go to save the FormView. I don't know what it is with FormView's, but they really don't seem to like dealing with a single record rather than multiple.

Comment: Let us know how it goes with that. I cannot reproduce this issue with my small stub application using a simple table but same formview, LDS, and code you have posted... which tells me there's something else still going on. Anything special in how viewstate, or controls, or anything of that nature is configured on your app?

Comment: By the way what version of .net are you running?

Comment: There's nothing special that I know of, like I said it works perfectly if I comment out the code in the `Selecting` event. I'm running .NET 4.0.

Comment: One thing I do have however are multiple GridViews embedded within the FormView. Each GridView has its own LinqDataSource with a ControlParameter, and each ControlParameter depends on Incident_Number which is shown in a text field in the main FormView. Is it possible that those LinqDataSources are trying to get that value before it's populated into that control? If so, why would it only break on update, and only one when the one record is shown in the FormView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, believe it or not this was solved by implementing the fix from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611347/is-this-a-formview-bug). Microsoft desperately needs to fix this. I changed the pager settings to show only at the bottom of the FormView and poof quit complaining.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. I scratched my head at this one for quite some time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
IQueryable<Incident> query = this.context.Incidents;
string whereCaluse = String.Format("Incident_Value=={0}",Request.QueryString["id"]);
query.Where(whereClause);
e.Result=query;
```

Comment: The `Where` method is expecting a predicate. If you mean to set `Where` on the LinqDataSource, I have tried that as well and it results in the same problem. It filters the data fine, but as soon as I try to save the FormView I get the exception above.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood you. I would suggest handling the OnUpdating Event as well if you aren't already. [Check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasourceupdateeventargs.aspx)

Comment: What should I be doing in that event?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at exception details, I can say that `i.Incident_Number` may be of object Type.

So, You can try converting `i.Incident_Number` to int as well in linq expression. like:

```
protected void ldsIncidents_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        e.Result = db.Incidents.Where(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Incident_Number) == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Inciden_Number` is the `Int32?`, my guess is `Request.QueryString['id']` is the object and for some reason it's not getting the value of the parameter at runtime.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being simplistic, or the coffee hasn't kicked in...but I don't think you can compare Int32? to int without doing .Value on the Int32?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use TryParse

```
protected void ldsIncidents_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {
        int id;
        e.Result = db.Incidents.Where(i => i.Incident_Number == Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id) ? id : 0);
    }
}
```

### Edit

to verify my suggestion below you could do this to check your values

```
    protected void ldsIncidents_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
        {
            int id;

            // now you can check the values you gat;
            var queryString = Request.QueryString["id"];
            int iNr =Int32.TryParse(queryString, out id) ? id : 0;

            e.Result = db.Incidents.Where(i => i.Incident_Number == iNr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll have to try this on Monday when I get back to work, thanks for the post.

Comment: @Hoff Let me know what about your result :). Have a nice weekend.

Comment: @Hoff where you able to fix your problem?

Comment: Nope, same problem unfortunately.

Comment: @Hoff wow that's interesting so one of your `i.Incident_Number` will be an object because the result of `Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id) ? id : 0` should now always be an `Int`

Comment: It's not throwing the exception in the `Selecting` event though according to the stack trace.

Comment: @Hoff so your `fvIncident` is a `TabContainer` and if you execute your `UpdateItem()` it blows up right? so i have to ask you a stupid question because i'm not in to asp is `UpdateItem()` a method from `TabContainer` or did you create it?

Comment: Nope, fvIncident is a FormView. If you take a look at my latest edit you'll see where the exception is thrown.